# How can I use a javascript library on the server side of a NodeJS app when it was designed to run on the client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, read-eval-print-loop

I'm diving into NodeJS and Express (it's sooo complicated to me) to build a real-time web app. At the moment, I'm trying to understand how I can use an existing javascript library on the server side. The problem is the library appears to be designed to run on the client side and, as a result, the instructions only show you how to use it on the client side. The library I'm talking about can be found here...

https://github.com/replit/jsrepl

Questions:

1. Since a NodeJS web app is built on javascript, is it fair to say I can run any non-gui javascript library on the server side?
2. Can anyone offer some guidance on how I can add that jsrepl library to my Express 3.0 app in a way that allows me to use it in the same way that I would use it on the client side in a browser?  Do I have to modify the jsrepl code and add "exports." to the methods I want to use?

Meaning, on the server side, I can execute the following code...

```
var jsrepl = new JSREPL({  
  input: inputCallback,  
  output: outputCallback,  
  result: resultCallback,  
  error: errorCallback,  
  progress: progressCallback,  
  timeout: {  
    time: 30000,  
    callback: timeoutCallback  
  }  
});
```

Thanks in advance for all your wisdom! I'm doing my best to understand all this.

Comment: +1 question. Interesting library - pure javascript python, scheme and lua interpreter. This library is just screaming to be ported over to node.js

Answer (score 9):

So this is possible, but you need some serious hackery in order to get it working. Since this is not a node module and is written from the browser as others have noted, you need a DOM within node to execute it into. Luckily, we have the wonderful [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) project which allows us to do just that. So let's get this thing set up.

- `cd` into your node project (create one if there isn't one already)
- clone down the jsrepl repo `git clone git://github.com/replit/jsrepl.git`
- cd into `jsrepl` and initialize submodules `git submodule update --init --recursive`
- still in the folder, run `npm install coffee-script` and `npm install uglify-js`, dependencies that are not mentioned anywhere in the repo (ugh).
- make sure java is installed and run `cake bake`. After a lengthy process of compiling java files and such the command will finish and jsrepl will be built and ready to go.
- run `npm install jsdom`, then we can start writing an example file

Here's a minimal example:

```
var jsdom = require('jsdom'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    jsrepl = fs.readFileSync('./jsrepl/repl.js', 'utf8');

jsdom.env({
  html: "<script src='jsrepl.js' id='jsrepl-script'></script> ",
  src: [jsrepl],
  done: function(err, window){
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    run_jsrepl.call(window);
  }
});

function run_jsrepl(){
  console.log(this.JSREPL)
}
```

Here's the minimum amount of code required to get `JSREPL` into a place where it's working. All we're doing here is requiring jsdom and instantiating it, reading in the jsrepl source straight from the file. If you run this file with `node filename` it will log out your `JSREPL` object, which can be used just like it's in the browser : )

Answer (score 2):

You can run [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/) in Node, which is a headless webkit browser. Then run jsrepl inside of phantomjs.

Answer (score 1):

1. No. There are things on the client side that you don't have on the server side (and vice-versa): for instance, the DOM.
2. I've never worked with `jsrepl` myself, but assuming that it's platform-agnostic, `require()`ing it from a node module should be OK. However, there seem to be some DOM-specific things in the scripts in question (e.g. `document.getElementById`) that suggest otherwise.

Comment: is correct. jsrepl won't work in a node environment as currently written. Perhaps this may help, http://nodejs.org/api/repl.html.

Comment: @ThaddeusAlbers: jsrepl is also able to directly execute coffeescript, scheme, lua and python so it's not just a simple REPL loop like the one in node core.