# Stress testing a JAvascript file which only runs in the browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockjs

I need to run a Javascript file for a relatively long time(maybe about 5 weeks or so at one time), without it stopping or being interrupted. Currently the script is a client side script which connects to the server and receives data via Sockjs. There is no HTMl/GUI. There is only some computation.

- I need to make sure the client always stays connected to the server all the time. I need to be able to run some script from the command line which is like forever.js. I have tried porting the javascript to node.js but it doesnt work. It only works in the browser. I have tried reading the file and doing an eval but none of it works. Are there any other options open for me? I have tried phantomJS but that doesnt work too. I have looked at [How can I use a javascript library on the server side of a NodeJS app when it was designed to run on the client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501160/how-can-i-use-a-javascript-library-on-the-server-side-of-a-nodejs-app-when-it-wa) and  [Load "Vanilla" Javascript Libraries into Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171213/load-vanilla-javascript-libraries-into-node-js) but I reapeatedly get SockJS is not defined. I guess the problem lies deep in the library and is not a simple fix.

Could anyone give me some pointers? What are my other options? Whats the best way to test a client javascript library which seems to work only on the browser?

This is the repo I am using :
https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client
It doesnt seems to be running on node. I tried to replace the script tag with require, and download the sock.js into a separate file and use it.

Comment: Anything that runs on the client without a UI should also be able to run in node -- though you might need a shim layer if you're doing Ajax calls.

Answer (score 0):

There are "headless" browser modules available. These produce a virtual browser environment that can be programatically controlled. The primary use of these is to do unit/integration testing of browser side code without actually running a browser:

1. [Phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/)
2. [Slimerjs](http://slimerjs.org/)

These might fit your needs. You can create a nodejs script that will load the said code in a virtual browser page.